# How do I access the web GUI of my NiFi instance running on an AWS machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-nifi

I am trying to run NiFi on an AWS machine and access the web GUI on my local computer.

I have followed guides such as: https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/47778/hdf-installation-on-ec2.html but whenever I type in the DNS:8080/nifi into my web browser I get a "connection refused" or timed out message.

I  have created an AWS Red Hat machine, installed NiFi + java, and edited the nifi.properties file such that it is now:

```
# Site to Site properties
nifi.remote.input.host=ec2-34-224-216-146.compute-1.amazonaws.com
nifi.remote.input.secure=false
nifi.remote.input.socket.port=
```

I have tried leaving the port number blank, as well as other numbers such as: `nifi.remote.input.socket.port=8082`
but neither work when I enter
`ec2-34-224-216-146.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/nifi` into my browser.

I have also tried adding the domain to my local computer's `/etc/hosts` file in the form of the Public DNS as well as IPv4. I have also configured the security group on AWS such that I have a "Custom TCP Rule" with the port range 8081, 8082, etc. for the respective ports I have attempted.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong or if I am missing a step. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The properties you are configuring are for site-to-site connections and are not related to the UI. These would be used if another NiFi or MiNiFi was making a site-to-site connection to your NiFi instance.

To control the UI you should be configuring:

```
nifi.web.http.host=
nifi.web.http.port=8080
nifi.web.https.host=
nifi.web.https.port=
```

Comment: so in order to access the UI, would I simply add some name to "nifi.web.http.host=" or do I need to add the IP address to my /etc/hosts file?

Comment: Set nifi.web.http.host to whatever hostname is publicly accessible. If you can go on the command line and run "ping <hostname>" successfully then you shouldn't need to modify /etc/hosts or anything else.